# MUI - Premium Data Grid toolbar icons are not appearing properly

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

I want to do three things -

1. Correct the display
2. Putting custom icons for the toolbar item
3. Add a custom toolbar option.

[image]

```
This is how I am using Datagrid.
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <DataGridPremium
      columns={columns}
      rows={rows}
      slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
      components={{
        Toolbar: GridToolbar,
      }}
      autoHeight
      checkboxSelection
    />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I am getting 


Uncaught Error: MUI: useGridRootProps should only be used inside the DataGrid, DataGridPro or DataGridPremium component.